# Does everyone make big mistakes?

Tags: emotion, behavior

It is sometimes said that we all make big mistakes.  Is this true?

As a starting point, 'big mistake' could be defined as a mistake which we do unconsciously for months, and for which the implications endure for more than a few months.

What is the best approach to recover from 'big mistakes'?

Comment: Welcome to the psychology and neuroscience forum.  In this forum, questions must be expressed in the third-person, that is, they should not related to oneself.  I've reworded your question and hope that it captures your question.

Comment: Edited the time of doing the mistake as well.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Unfortunately, the definition of "big mistake" is far too vague to be answerable on this forum.  Humans are susceptible to a long list of cognitive and memory biases that are unconscious and have long-term repercussions, just for a start.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple and obvious answer to this question is "Yes".  That is, everyone at some point in their life is likely to make a 'big mistake'.

Regret is the likely emotion felt subsequent to making a 'big mistake' and is a well researched topic as per the references below.

There are countless situations in which an individual is likely to feel the emotion of regret, including: divorce, bankruptcy, loss of a close friend, self-inflicted injury, resigning from employment in a rage, being sentenced to jail etc. (The examples chosen here are likely to reflect instances where the big mistake endures for more than a few months.

Clinical psychology is the profession with specific training for helping individuals move on from their mistakes and overcoming a deep-set emotion of regret.

**References**

- Connolly T, Zeelenberg M. Regret in Decision Making. Current Directions in Psychological Science. 2002;11(6):212-216. https://doi.org/10.1111/1467-8721.00203
- Sweis BM, Thomas MJ, Redish AD (2018) Mice learn to avoid regret. PLoS Biol 16(6): e2005853. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.2005853